# Gcloud background functions with depedencies fail to deploy

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, serverless

Below is a basic example of gcloud background function with a dependency in it. On using `uuid` package it throws up an error although package.json has `uuid`

On deploying following erros is received.

```
gcloud beta functions deploy helloPubSub --trigger-resource my-topic --trigger-event google.pubsub.topic.publish

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'uuid'
```

index.js

```
const uuid = require('uuid');

exports.helloPubSub = (event, callback) => {

  const pubsubMessage = event.data;

  const eventName = pubsubMessage.data ? Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString() : 'World';

  console.log(eventName,uuid.v4());

  callback();

};
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "uuid": "^3.2.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue in my .gcloudignore

Below change did make it work!

From

```
node_modules/
```

to

```
node_modules
```